# Debugging Vue application in MS Edge: no extensions available

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, microsoft-edge

Is there a way to enable Microsoft Edge extensions during debug sessions? This is a Vue 3 application and I'm using the following `launch.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Frontend",
  "type": "pwa-msedge",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "https://localhost:8080/",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
  "breakOnLoad": false,
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "pathMapping": {
    "/_karma_webpack_": "${workspaceFolder}"
  },
  "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "webpack://vue4/./src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
    "webpack://vue4/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
  },
},
```

For some reason, Microsoft Edge does not load any extensions when I press <kbd>F5</kbd> in VSCode. Not only that, there is no extension shown in Edge Settings either. Looks like VScode instructs Edge to load with some *no-extensions* argument, but I can't figure out where and how to change that.

I'm primarily concerned about the **Vue** tab in DevTools. This tab (and all other extensions) loads automatically when I open Edge normally, but not when launched from VSCode.

Comment: You mean the extensions in Edge are gone when you start the program via vscode, right? If this is the case, I think these two tests may used different profiles. You can navigate to `edge://version` and see if the `Profile path` is the same after opening Edge separately.

Comment: @XudongPeng: Yep. You're right. It is `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default` when I open it normally, but `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-edge-debug-userdatadir_2015\Default` when I open it through VSCode. Means edge installs extensions per user, not per machine. Should have been obvious now that I think about it. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Glad my reply was helpful to you. And if this is the case, you need to adjust the corresponding configuration to point the same `profile path`, which should fix this problem.